# Verify if the number is not greater than 12 through regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to do a validation through regex where a string should be no more than 12 characters and first character should be `a`, `b` or `c` in *small* or *capital* and the rest *digits*.

Eg :
Pass Scenarios :

```
A1, B12, C123, A1234, B12345, C123456, A1234567, B12345678, C123456789, A123435678901, B12345678901
```

Fail Scenarios :

```
B123456789012, S123 (Any value greater than 12 and not starting with A B C)
```

Thanks for your help.

I tried using

```
@"(^[abcABC]{1})([0-9]|11$)"
```

Comment: The pass scenario "A123435678901" is actually a fail scenario.

Comment: `...and first "number" should be a, b or c...` :)

Comment: `^[a-cA-C][0-9]{1,11}$`

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick
`^[aAbBcC]\d{1,11}$`